# Django gather instance from selectable inputs of multiple models and post to another model

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I didn't even know how to write what I want to achieve on the title. I have 3 models, lets say:

- Country
- City: foreign key yo country
- Person: foreign key yo city

Each of them has it's own attributes and those foreign keys I've shown.
What I want to do is, write a form that has 2 selectable fields, one for country and another for city. An providing those two values, It get's the instance of Person so that the rest of the fields get rendered and the user populates them in order to save it on the database.

I've seen that in order to display cities according to the country provided I need to write some javascript, but they show how to do it if the model that holds the foreign keys is just one. In my case there are three, one references the other.

Is this achievable? If so could someone guide me towards the solution? Thanks!

Comment: You can easily write a database query that searches for all users that are linked to that city (the country seems irrelevant because it is determined by the country). But why do you assume that this will have a unique result?

Comment: I'm using defaults sqlite database currently, but those are not the exact models. It was just so that I could explain. But there's a restriction that there's only one 'person' from a 'city' and a 'country'. There are many countries and cities, but a one to one relationship between 'person' and 'city'. Country would be relevant because that's the first input that the user will provide in order to filter cities outputs.